# How can I compress a directory, and convert soft to hard links?

Tags: bash, compression, symlink, tar, rhel

I would like to compress a directory.

```
tar -cvzf mydir.tar.gz mydir
```

but this retains symlinks so that it is not portable to a new system.

How can I convert symlinks?

I have tried

```
tar -cvzfh
```

since `man tar` says

> -h, --dereference
>
> ```
>           don’t dump symlinks; dump the files they point to
> ```

but this results in an error

```
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

and creates a file called "zh"

My files are on a RHEL server.

Answer (score 5):

Your tar.gz file name **must** follow immediately after the `-f` flag, merely reordering the flags may work.

```
tar -cvzhf mydir.tar.gz mydir
```